# Prove the generalized solution to the normal equations $X'Xb = X'y$

Tags: matrices, statistics, proof-verification

I am just learning how to write these statistical proofs with matrices. Please check and revise:
Prove $(X'X)^-X'y$ is a solution to the normal equations.

Let the solution to the normal equations be written $X'Xb=X'y$.

If $\operatorname{rank}(X) = p$,         - Definition of full col rank

Then $X'X$ is invertible              - Property of matrices

$[(X'X)^-]X'Xb=X'y(X'X)^-$    - Multiply both sides by inverse.

$[X'X)^-]X'Xb = \hat\beta$        - Definition of $\hat\beta$ parameter.

$\hat\beta=(X'X)^-X'y$          - Substitute, reorder.

Is this complete, or what am I missing?